# Axios returns HTML response (Laravel +VUE)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, single-page-application

I have two Route in my `api.php`.

> ```
> Route::get('resume-list/{templateID}', 'BasicController@getAllResumes');
> Route::get('resume/single/{id}', 'BasicController@getResume');
> ```

The first one works fine but the second route returns the html code of index page.

Below is the axios call for the route:

```
data() {
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        data: {}
    };
},
methods: {
    loadData() {
        axios.get("api/resume/single/" + this.id).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.data = response;
        });
    }
},

created() {
    this.loadData();
}
```

**Function on backend**

```
public function getResume($id)
{
    return Basic::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

What is the cause for this code?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

**Bootstrap.js**

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('admin-lte');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Comment: are you returning json from getResume?

Comment: `$response = Basic::findOrFail($id); return response()->json($response);` simply do this and check

Comment: Did but still not working. I did `dd($id)` inside `getResume` function. But still get HTML code on `console.log`. I think the route is not reaching to the controller function.

Comment: Have you globally set the `api` baseurl for the axios ? And also have you set `ContentType: application/json` these things in axios ?

Comment: Yes, the first route is also called by axios and it works perfectly.

Comment: ``/api/resume/single/${this.$route.params.id}`` use these ` ` quotes, it won't show but you can use the quotes which is on a button below `ESC` on your keyboard

Comment: Didn't understand your code

Comment: Updated my code

Comment: get(`/api/resume/single/${this.$route.params.id}`) this portion of your code, instead of using " " qoutes, use only these quotes ` ` remember it's not a single quote, wrap your full route in these ` ` also your baseUrl is important because you will need to change url in request according to baseUrl.

Comment: Did as you have mentioned and the result is same HTML code

Comment: Im not sure if you are handling `json` correctly but normally data will be in `response.data`

Comment: Is your vuejs included inside laravel or it is seperate from laravel ? If you have it inside laravel then upload your `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file code as well, because it seems you are not hitting the actual route

Comment: Maybe this a typo, but the url in your api call is `api/single/resume/` but laravel route is `resume/single/{id}`: one is `single/resume` the other is `resume/single`

Comment: Yeha, I had also noticed and fixed it earlier. But still no progress

Comment: @PawanRai can you share a screenshot of this HTML response since it could be an error response? Akhthar Munir is asking for bootstrap code as well. I think a screenshot or the code could save a lot of time.

Comment: I'm running the axios code on `http://localhost:8000/show-resume/1` url. I have no idea how the axios call is hitting ` http://localhost:8000/show-resume/api/resume/single/1`

Comment: I am asking for `bootstrap.js` file code, unless can't help you then. You might have done something wrong in your global setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make your setting in this way**

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('admin-lte');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');
//window.axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.APP_URL;
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Content-Type':'application/json',
   'Accept':'application/json'
   };


let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

Now your axios call will become

loadData() {
    axios.get(`/api/resume/single/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

OR

"/api/resume/single/"+this.id
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. What was wrong with my configs ??

Comment: welcome, you were not hitting the url correclty, that's why, I have configured a baseUrl in your global axios setting and also `application/json` these things were missing.

Answer (score 2):

try to convert manual - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses

if it doesn't work, the problem is configuring the router

Comment: It should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I think the route is not reaching to the controller method as I did dd($id) it still returns HTML code while it should have returned it in the network tab of devtool.

Comment: Is your vuejs a seperate project or it's included inside laravel ? @PawanRai

Comment: It is inside laravel